# Java - How to set propOrder attribute dynamically within @XmlType

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

I have a class with xml annotations that will be instantiated then used to generated a xml file.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "foo", "bar", "baz"
})
public class MyClass {

    @XmlElement(name = "foo", required = true)
    protected String foo;

    @XmlElement(name = "bar", required = true)
    protected String bar;

    @XmlElement(name = "baz", required = true)
    protected String baz;

    ...
}
```

I would like to set the attribute `propOrder` dynamically using a variable (`version` for example) like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = version.equals("1") ? {"foo", "bar", "baz"} : {"bar", "baz", "foo"}
)
public class MyClass {

    @XmlElement(name = "foo", required = true)
    protected String foo;

    @XmlElement(name = "bar", required = true)
    protected String bar;

    @XmlElement(name = "baz", required = true)
    protected String baz;

    ...
}
```

So based on this `version` parameter, the xml file generated will look like

```
<foo></foo>
<bar></bar>
<baz></baz>

or 

<bar></bar>
<baz></baz>
<foo></foo>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible. Annotations are handled in compile time.

PS: It is impossible in pure java. If you really want you can use some kind of preprocessor.